# Using a through hole right angle switch

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, datasheet

I am designing a PCB, and it needs to have a right angle tactile switch. I am going to use a through hole, since it should offer added strength compared to a surface mount.

I am looking at the data sheet of this switch: [Datasheet PDF](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/418/NG_CD_1825027_G4-659966.pdf)

[image: IMG]

Looking at the schematic, pin 1 and 2 are the switching pins. It doesn't specifically say which pins are 1 and 2 however. From past knowledge, I assume those pins are the two inner ones.

Assuming I am correct, the outer pins just connect to each other, to add strength to the switch. Is it best practice to solder them both to the ground plane? Or just have an unconnected copper trace for them? Or just a hole, and leave them unsoldered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer "pins" are simply there for support. They should not be connected to any net. Just make two pads sized for them and don't connect the pads to any traces. They are only there to hold the switch in place. You definitely should solder them.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was thinking. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

You should provide a (safe) path for [ESD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge) current from the two frame terminals.

Usually that will be circuit ground, as shown in the below [datasheet](https://www.rapidonline.com/pdf/78-1152.pdf) for a similar switch.

[image]